# How to update observable array on load more

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to update Observable array after click on load more but it result in multiple call to API.

Here is my html:

```
<app-productlistother *ngFor="let item  of favs$ | async" [item]="item"></app-productlistother>

<a (click)="loadMore()">Load More</a>
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.favs$ = this._favoriteService.getFavorites(this.pageNum);
  }

  private loadMore() {
    this.pageNum = this.pageNum + 1;

    this.favs$ = this.favs$.merge(this._favoriteService.getFavorites(this.pageNum));
  }
```

And service:

```
getFavorites(page): Observable<Response> {
    return this._http.get(environment.baseUrl + 'favorite?page=' + page)
      .map((result: Response) => result.json().data);
  }
```

How can I solve this? On each new request to `getFavorites(page)` I need to push new results on bottom of array...

Comment: you need a observable in your service and need to subscribe to the obeservable in the component and once load more is triggred , data will be added to the observable and the component will be listing for any change and then update itself

Comment: Could you show me example?

Comment: @Vladmir gave an example hope it helps

Comment: Looking at your HTML, you're repeating <app-productlistother> and passing in a new item as an input to a child component. What does the <app-productlistother> HTML look like? I have a feeling you're asyncing each item, instead of asyncing once and repeating over the items of the async.

Comment: In `<app-productlistother>` I just display like this `{{item.name}}`

Comment: So you have no HTML and `<app-productionother>` template is just `{{item.name}}` ? In that case, why not structure it like this:

    `<ng-template *ngFor="let item of favs$ | async">
        <app-productlistother [item]="item></app-productlistother>
    </ng-template>`

This keeps the async pipe off the repeating element so the async pipe isn't being repeated on each iteration of item

Comment: @Vladimir did this help any?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyBooleanService {
    myBool$: Observable<any>;

    private boolSubject: Subject<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.boolSubject = new Subject<any>();
        this.myBool$ = this.boolSubject.asObservable();
    }

    ...some code that emits new values using this.boolSubject...
}
```

Then in your component you would have something like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    currentBool: any;

    constructor(service: MyBooleanService) {
        service.myBool$.subscribe((newBool: any) => { this.currentBool = newBool; });
    }
}
```

Now depending on what you need to do with that value you may need to do chnages in your component to update, but this is the gist of using an observable

Another option is you use the async pipe within your template instead of explicitly subscribing to the stream in the constructor. Again though, that depends on what exactly you need to do with the bool values.

Comment: I don't need to subscribe Observable async pipe do it for me I just need to add new observable to the current.

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: I don't use subscribe in my code, async pipe do it for me... I need after load more function to merge 2 observables  into 1

Comment: then do not use observable in the example you can use it with async pipe in your template, updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

So you have no HTML and `<app-productionother>` template is just `{{item.name}}` ? In that case, why not structure it like this:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let item of favs$ | async"> 
    <app-productlistother [item]="item"></app-productlistother> 
</ng-template>
```

This keeps the async pipe off the repeating element so the async pipe isn't being repeated on each iteration of item. I think that's why it's being called multiple times (likely the same number as you have items).

Also, if `merge` isn't working out, try `concat`. `Concat` will wait until the first observable is finished emitting and then will join the second observable. Merge doesn't wait for the first observable to finish. I imagine you'd want your data to load in order if you click load more and not have initial data interweaved with the second batch, or so on.